# comm.jar communicating serial ports java

Tags: java, serial-port

I am facing problem with using comm.jar.

Problem is I connected the devices and I started the application in pooling using this code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enumeration portList;
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            System.out.println("port::" + portId.getName());

        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaComPortFinding.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            main(args);
        }
    }
```

**output :**

```
port::COM1
port::COM10
```

After one polling , I have ejected the device. I still get the response as

```
port::COM1
port::COM10
```

can anyone help me out / suggest to get dynamic response in polling.

Comment: First of all, your application is recursive, which is bad. Second, have you verified if your driver stay loaded ? (Under Windows you can see under Devices Manager > Ports).

Comment: You are right @AlexandreLavoie. @rajuthoutu just in case, it means: why  are you calling the `main` method inside itself?

Comment: Hi  @AlexandreLavoie thanks for responding,After removing the device Manager > Ports are not stayed. Actually i am developing standalone application , situation where i need to check often times whether the device is connected or not (if connected then msgs will send automatically to the respectives).but in the second case i am getting failure which shouldn't come.

Comment: Really strange, I've never used RXTX with USB to serial for the moment so I can't help you more on that. If you run your program again ie : Connect your device, run your program (COM10 detected), disconnect your device, run your program (COM10 detected or not?)

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie not detected. when it is in pooling case only i am facing problem

Comment: @emecas that is a kind of requirement for my application

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that since the CommPortIdentifier should be recreated every time.

```
class TestProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(TestProgram.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            scanPorts();
        }
    }

    private static void scanPorts()
    {
        Enumeration portList;
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        while (portList.hasMoreElements())
        {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            System.out.println("port::" + portId.getName());

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

I've just tested the program on Windows XP SP3 with my BlackBerry on usb. When I start the program I see the normal COM1 and two COM ports for the BlackBerry. Once I disconnect the BlackBerry, the ports stay in the device manager. If I remove them manually, they dissapear in the program (without restart).

Comment: i tried this thing earlier but result is the same.i have a doubt like the ports list is once its get initialized then till the application is alive getting same responses. Do you agree with it or any kind of thing?

Comment: Ya it seems problem with windows.But still the problem remains the same for me. I tried  with my device like what u  did.But the result is the same (windows xp sp3 only).

Comment: @rajuthoutu any progress on this?

Comment: @emecas No, still it is the same. i think it is the problem with dll and comm.jar .Can you look into it once.

Answer (score 0):

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2063873?start=0&tstart=0

I found the above resource extremely valuable while finding solution for a similar issue.

The main problem here is that static block in `CommPortIdentifier` gets loaded only once and caches the ports information in field variable `portList`. When you call the `getPortIdentifiers()` method, it will return the ports from `portList` which were detected during the initial load.

The workaround this would be to reload the static block in `CommPortIdentifier` class and then call `getPortIdentifiers()`, which will reload the drivers and give you an updated list of COM ports (this was done using Java Reflection API in the link referenced).

Good Luck!